# What is a word for "almost hits"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing from the point of view of a soldier in WW1 and I have a sentence:

> I am in constant fear for my life, and nearly every second that bullets and shrapnel are not **(insert word)** I am praying that this war will end soon.

Comment: I'm guessing that your ***almost hits*** are what native speakers would call ***near misses***, but I don't see any easy / natural way of introducing that into your sample context.

Comment: In your context, I'd expect a verb or verb phrase, something like "raining down around me": "*I am in constant fear for my life, and nearly every second that bullets and shrapnel are not **raining down around me** I am praying that this war will end soon.*" But that isn't at all what I would expect as an answer to the question in your title, which seems to be asking for a noun or noun phrase like @FumbleFingers suggestion. Could you edit to clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: "I am in constant fear for my life, and nearly every second that bullets and shrapnel are not _killing me,_ I am praying that this war will end soon."

Comment: Hahaha I am a native speaker, I am looking for a verb, near miss is a noun. I was looking for a close replacement to "whizz by," but more eloquent. @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 3):

Consider writing

> I am in constant fear for my life, and nearly every second that
>   bullets and shrapnel **narrowly miss** me, I am praying that this war will
>   end soon.

Answer (score 2):

whizzing around me

> [whizz](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whizz): [with adverbial of direction] Move quickly through the air with a whistling or buzzing sound: ‘the missiles whizzed past’

*(Oxford)*

This is a standard way of talking about bullets moving near a person.  If you prefer, you could say "whizzing past me."